# Why have MTB tyres with strong front / back design disappeared?

Tags: tire, wheels, vintage, design

Back a few years ago was easy to find tyres with a particular design based on their position, back or front, see this sample image fron a pair of Nokian Boazobeana:

[image]

Riding with those was pretty nice, especially with the front one, which provides a great driving precision and security.

So it's strange why is so hard to find something similar in the market today, someone knows why?

Comment: Which of the two pictured is which? I have a guess but I'm not sure

Comment: @Chris H Should be left front, right rear. The line of centre tread is pretty telling on the rear tire.

Comment: @MaplePanda but on the other hand the right looks designed to resist side slipping (important at the front) while the left might provide more traction (assuming mud with enough lumps to grip onto)

Comment: @Chris H Google tells me your hypothesis is correct!

Comment: Hah! Oldster here. The right is the front and the left is the rear. Rear tires usually have some some of "paddlewheel" style tread to allow the drive wheel to power you forward.  Here's an example: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0202/9884/products/VelociRaptor_group_side_1024x1024.jpg?v=1568918444

Answer (score 9):

They haven't

https://www.schwalbe.com/en/mtb-reader/eddy-current-rear

"FRONT:
• Reliable cornering grip paired with high braking traction.
• Excellent transmission of steering corrections throughlong grip edges even when less weight is on the front wheel in ascents. The result: Understeer is more controllable.

REAR:
• Maximum propulsion and braking traction throughmassive blocks that transmit sufficient power to the ground, even on the steepest climbs.
• Hard wearing thanks to large-volume center studs."

https://www.schwalbe.com/en/mtb-reader/racing-ray

"RACING RAY
THE FRONT WHEEL SPECIALIST. The completely new, extra aggressive XC profile paired with the versatile Addix Speedgrip compound makes Racing Ray a XC weapon and an ingenious addition to Racing Ralph."

Also

https://www.schwalbetires.com/bike_tires/off-road_tires/fat_albert_front_477

Also given that rolling resistance is more important at the back due to weight distribution, it's common for riders to mix tyres, so you don't really need a 'front' and 'rear' tyre designated as such, you can just choose two different tyres - a harder compound and/or less grippy pattern at the back, and a softer compound with more knobs at the front. Also different tyre widths is common.

See e.g. here

https://www.mbr.co.uk/news/product_news/best-mountain-bike-tyres-323130

Answer (score 6):

This is simply not true. Many high range MTB tires are specifically designated for front or back usage, and practically all tire reviews mention that.

Certain manufacturers have encoded the "front/back" purpose of their tires in their names. Maxxis Minion DH**F** is meant for front, while Maxxis Minion DH**R** is meant for the rear. Of course, many people use them differently, depending on their riding style and riding conditions. It is not uncommon to see a "front" tire at the rear, for example.

Tire thread designs have changed somewhat over the time (but so have the bicycles). It is unusual to find tires with the "angled" profile (`>>>>>>>`) as your pictures show  at the higher end of the market, where the rear/back distinction is important.

Modern gravity tires are all more blocky (`▓▓▓▓`), cf. Schwalbe design, but others look quite similar:

[image: Magic Mary]